# Why capacitor pass AC and block DC current?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, electronics

We know that in circuit capacitor block the DC current and pass AC current. My question is how a capacitor block DC and pass AC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I wonder why I cannot charge a capacitor with alternating current?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135408/)

Comment: The simple answer is that you can, but also the charge of the capacitor will alternate. Check the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a circuit with a capacitor, a voltage source, and a switch. Suppose the voltage source is DC and we flip the switch. If the capacitor is initially uncharged, then at the instant you close the switch current will flow as if the capacitor was not there. Instead of an electron crossing the capacitor, an electron will arrive at the negative capacitor plate and another electron will leave the positive plate. So, at first, current can flow, but as the charge builds up the capacitor begins to oppose the voltage placed on it and eventually there is no more current in the system because the capacitor is charged and at equal voltage to the DC voltage source.

Now suppose we did the same thing with an AC source. We close the switch, current flows, the capacitor starts building up charge to stop the current...but then the voltage flips around and the capacitor no longer opposes the current, so the current can flow the other way, the capacitor starts to change its polarity, but as it does the current changes AGAIN...etc.

In short, when a capacitor is placed in a DC circuit it very quickly becomes charged in such a way as to oppose the applied voltage and all current stops. When the power source is AC, however, the capacitor never has time to "adapt" to it and so won't build up a charge that opposes the current. It's like you keep flipping an hourglass back over.

Comment: I think only a Electrolytic capacitor bypasses AC and block DC because in this capacitor there are two plates, one is aluminium foil and another is a foil wet by noncorrosive salt solution. When first is positively charged w.r.t the later, the solution liberates $H_2$ gas which forma a thin gas layer on the first plate and hence a large capacitance is obtained. But when AC voltage is applied the thin hydrogen layer is not formed the polarity of the voltage changes. And hence for AC current capacitor acts as a conductor.

Comment: No, even a simple parallel plate capacitor builds up the opposing voltage as I described. We don't have to invoke the specific way the capacitor works (although we can). In your case, the hydrogen layer never has "time to form" because the voltage switches back. (I think, I am not very familiar with this model of a capacitor.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the work of capacitor is to store energy from the moving electric current. As DC flow of current is unidirectional, the current flows ant gets stored in the capacitors. Whereas ac current signals change there direction after every round so it is not blocked by the capacitors

Answer (score -1):

The capacitor equation as we all know is Q=CV

Where the symbols denote the usual values

We know that the current I= (dQ/dt)

let V=v*sin(wt)

=> Q=C*(vsin(wt))

dQ/dt=I= w*C*v*cos(wt)  ----------------(1)

and we know that V=IR -------------------(2)

re-arranging the terms in eq (1)

v*cos(wt)= (1/wC)*I  ---------------------(3)

comparing eqs (2) and (3)

we can write resistance R=(1/wC)

notice that R is inversely proportional to frequency

which implies that for dc, w=0

which gives R = infinity 
or it gives infinite resistance for DC, so completely blocks it

Comment: Use latex-style typesetting to make your answer legible

Comment: sorry I'm new here. I need to start learning latex, Thanks for pointing out